# Best way to open a PTY with PHP

Tags: php, linux, terminal, tty, pty

### Problem description

I would like to open a Linux pseudoterminal with PHP but it seems there is no simple way of doing that. I have experimented with different solutions but none seem to be good enough.
The goal of the PTY is to emulate a terminal with the capability of flawlessly interacting with programs such as `zsh` and `sudo`. Other programming languages including Python and C have functions or libraries for that. Python has the [PTY library](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/pty.html) which can simply do `pty.spawn("/bin/zsh")`, and C has the [`openpty()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/openpty) function.

My ideal end goal is to have a PHP function that allows me to read and write from/into the PTY terminal and does not require installing external libraries. (A lot of shared hosting providers do not allow that.)

### What I have tried so far

**Using proc_open()**

My initial idea was just to use the `proc_open()` PHP function to create a Bash terminal with `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` pipes (Based on Example #1 in the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)) This, however, did soon prove to be problematic because it is actually not a real PTY. Running `stty -a` errored with `stty: stdin isn't a terminal`. Here are the instructions for reproducing this.

1. Run this with `php pty_test.php`
2. Read the output of the shell with `cat /tmp/stdout`.
3. Input commands with `> /tmp/stdin`.

Here is the PHP code which I used for this:

```
<?php
/* pty_test.php */


ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_ūūerrors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define("STD_IN", 0);
define("STD_OUT", 1);
define("STD_ERR", 2);

set_time_limit(0);
umask(0);

$chunk_size = 1400;
$write_a = null;
$error_a = null;
$shell = "/bin/sh -i ";
$stdin_fifo = "/tmp/stdin";
$stdout_fifo = "/tmp/stdout";

posix_mkfifo($stdin_fifo, 0644);
posix_mkfifo($stdout_fifo, 0644);
$resource_stdin = fopen($stdin_fifo, "rb+");
$resource_stdout = fopen($stdout_fifo, "wb+");

$descriptorspec = array(
   STD_IN => array("pipe", "rb"),
   STD_OUT => array("pipe", "wb"),
   STD_ERR => array("pipe", "wb")
);

$process = proc_open($shell, $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, $env = null);

stream_set_blocking($pipes[STD_IN], 0);
stream_set_blocking($pipes[STD_OUT], 0);
stream_set_blocking($pipes[STD_ERR], 0);
stream_set_blocking($resource_stdin, 0);
stream_set_blocking($resource_stdout, 0);

while (1) {

    $read_a = array($resource_stdin, $pipes[STD_OUT], $pipes[STD_ERR]);
    $num_changed_streams = stream_select($read_a, $write_a, $error_a, null);
    
    if (in_array($resource_stdin, $read_a)) {
        $input = fread($resource_stdin, $chunk_size);
        fwrite($pipes[STD_IN], $input);
    }
    if (in_array($pipes[STD_OUT], $read_a)) {
        $input = fread($pipes[STD_OUT], $chunk_size);
        fwrite($resource_stdout, $input);
    }
    if (in_array($pipes[STD_ERR], $read_a)) {
        $input = fread($pipes[STD_ERR], $chunk_size);
        fwrite($resource_stdout, $input);
    }
}

fclose($resource_stdin);
fclose($resource_stdout);
fclose($pipes[STD_IN]);
fclose($pipes[STD_OUT]);
fclose($pipes[STD_ERR]);
proc_close($process);
unlink($stdin_fifo);
unlink($stdout_fifo);

?>
```

**Python PTY**

I noticed that running `python3 -c "import pty;pty.spawn('/bin/bash');"` in the non-pty shell (which I described above) will result in a fully interactive PTY shell as I desired. This resulted in a half-good solution: setting the `$shell` variable to be `python3 -c "import pty;pty.spawn('/bin/bash')"` will spawn the interactive shell using Python3. But relying on external software is not ideal since having Python3 is not always guaranteed. (And this solution also feels way too hacky...)

**/dev/ptmx**

I was reading the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/proc_open.c) of the `proc_open()` function also found the source for `openpty()`. Unfortunately, PHP can't directly call this function but perhaps it is possible to replicate the behavior of it.
I could `fopen("/dev/ptmx","r+")` to create a new slave but `openpty()` also uses  `grantpt()` and `unlockpt()`, which are not available in PHP.

**Foreign Function Interface**
[FFI](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ffi.examples-basic.php) allows access to external libraries. Maybe it would be possible to import `pty.h` and to run `openpty()`. Unfortunately, FFI is very experimental and may not always be available.

### TL;DR

What is the safest and most reliable way to spawn a PTY using PHP?

Comment: What about [expect_popen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.expect-popen.php)? I know it depends on PECL extension, but just in case...

Answer (score 4):

You do not have to use FFI to write PHP shared library.

I just tried to write an open source PHP library for this purpose. I named it TeaOpenPTY. I think this can be a good example how to write a simple PHP library in C.

---

- GitHub repo: https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/TeaOpenPTY
- Precompiled Shared Lib: https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/TeaOpenPTY/raw/master/compiled/tea_openpty.so

---

## How to use the TeaOpenPTY library?

### File test.php

```php
<?php

use TeaOpenPTY\TeaOpenPTY;

$app  = "/usr/bin/bash";
$argv = [$app, "-i"];

$teaOpenPTY = new TeaOpenPTY($app);

echo "Starting TeaOpenPTY...\n";

$ret = $teaOpenPTY->exec(...$argv);

if ($ret === -1) {
  echo "Error: ", $teaOpenPTY->error(), "\n";
}

echo "TeaOpenPTY terminated!\n";
```

### Run

```
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ wget https://github.com/ammarfaizi2/TeaOpenPTY/raw/master/compiled/tea_openpty.so
[...output abbreviated...]
2020-12-28 14:39:20 (612 KB/s) - ‘tea_openpty.so’ saved [19048/19048]

ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ echo $$ # Show the current bash PID
19068
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ php -d extension=$(pwd)/tea_openpty.so test.php
Starting TeaOpenPTY...
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ echo $$ # Now we are in the terminal spawned by tea_openpty
329423
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 46; columns 192; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ exit # Terminate the terminal
exit
TeaOpenPTY terminated!
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$ echo $$
19068
ammarfaizi2@integral:/tmp$
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution but I'm not yet going to mark it as the solution since I am looking for a solution that does not require external libraries. I will make sure to edit my original question to clarify that.